# Pandas dataframe groupby / rolling - why no reset of rolling mean on new group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I'm trying to summarise worked hours for a group of people and need to calculate a rolling average.

I can do this with df.groupby and df.rolling but for a rolling average of 'n' values, I expect the first n-1 values in a group to be nan or 0.

Example  -

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

employees = ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob' ]
weeks = [2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
hours = [5, 8, 4, 2, 5]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'employee' : employees,
        'week': weeks,
       'hours': hours})
       
df.groupby(['employee', 'week']).sum().rolling(2).mean()

df

  employee  hours  week
0  Alice  5  2
1  Alice  8  3
2  Bob  4  2
3  Bob  2  3
4  Bob  5  4
```

Result -

```html
           hours
employee week       
Alice    2       NaN
     3       6.5
Bob      2       6.0  <-- expect this to be 0
     3       3.0
     4       3.5
```

Expected result

```html
           hours
employee week       
Alice    2       NaN
     3       6.5
Bob      2       NaN  <--- mean reset to 0 on new group
     3       3.0
     4       3.5
```

This reset (1st row of Bob) doesn't happen. How can I make it happen?

Many thanks (and apols for formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
s=df.groupby(['employee']).apply(lambda x : x['hours'].rolling(2).mean())
s
Out[225]: 
employee   
Alice     0       nan
          1   6.50000
Bob       2       nan
          3   3.00000
          4   3.50000
Name: hours, dtype: float64

# assign it back 
df['roll_mean']=s.reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```